# How to access the sibbling node of parent in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have various questions on my **faq** page like this

```
<h3><a href="#" onclick="this.parent.nextSibbling.style=toggle_display()">How to signup?</a></h3>
<div class="info" style="display:none">
    This is the hidden answer
</div>
```

The answer is hidden and when the user clicks on the link the `div` below it appears.Though I can do this using jquery easily but I don't want to make the page heavy so I simply using the following function

```
function toggle_display()
    {   

         var answers=document.getElementsByClassName("info");
         for(var i=0;i<answers.length;i++)
         {  
             //hide all the divs first
             answers[i].style.display='none';
        }
           //return block as style so that the caller's div answer can be set to block
        return 'block';
}
```

But I am having problem accessing the next sibbling `div` of the link.What should I substitute in the following line

```
<a href="#" onclick="**this.parent.nextSibbling**.style=toggle_display()">
```

Comment: I would suggest to consult a [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) instead of guessing property-names

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the next sibling of parent node then your code should be like this.

```
this.parentNode.nextSibling
```

Comment: :I am getting error :`this.parentNode.nextSibling` is undefined

Comment: Are you sure you are putting, `this.parentNode.nextSibling` not as `this.parentNode.nextSibbling` in your question?

Answer (score 0):

For ignoring text dom nodes and get the right one element use:

```
this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.style = ......
```

Comment: :I already tried this ,I am getting error :`this.parentElement.nextElementSibbling` is undefined

Comment: can't help you, try move your onclick listener to javascript (not html attribute) and debug the code using breakpoints and watch variables in chrome dev tools